# Addition corresponding to all possible combination of two columns based on a criteria

Tags: r, combinations

I have the following input

```
| ID | Column1 | Column2 | Value |
|:-- |:-------:|:-------:| -----:|
| A  |    x    |    a    |   4   |
| A  |    x    |    b    |   1   |
| A  |    y    |    a    |   5   |
| A  |    y    |    b    |   6   |
| B  |    u    |    a    |   9   |
| B  |    u    |    b    |   2   |
| B  |    v    |    a    |   7   |
| B  |    v    |    b    |   4   |
| B  |    w    |    a    |   1   |
| B  |    w    |    b    |   3   |
```

I am looking to get the following output where values in output would be addition of possible combinations of column 1 and column 2 in input for every ID, similar to below

```
| ID |     Column1    |    Value    |
|:-- |:--------------:| -----------:|
| A  |    xa+ya       |    4+5      |
| A  |    xa+yb       |    4+6      |
| A  |    xb+ya       |    1+5      |
| A  |    xb+yb       |    1+6      |
| B  |    ua+va+wa    |    9+7+1    |
| B  |    ua+va+wb    |    9+7+3    |
| B  |    ua+vb+wa    |    9+4+1    |
| B  |    ua+vb+wb    |    9+4+3    |
| B  |    ub+va+wa    |    2+7+1    |
| B  |    ub+va+wb    |    2+7+3    |
| B  |    ub+vb+wa    |    2+4+1    |
| B  |    ub+vb+wb    |    2+4+3    |
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic for combinations is not very clear.  Maybe this helps - `paste` (`str_c` from `stringr`), the 'Column1', 'Column2' to a single column, then grouped by 'ID', `summarise` the 'ColumnA' with `combn`ations to `paste` the elements, while getting the `sum` from `Value` column, then `filter` out the combinations that are not needed based on the unique values in 'Column1'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(ColumnA = str_c(Column1, Column2)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(ColumnA = combn(ColumnA, n_distinct(Column1), 
     FUN = str_c, collapse = "+"), 
  Value = combn(Value, n_distinct(Column1), FUN = sum), .groups = 'drop')  %>% 
  mutate(new1 = str_remove_all(ColumnA, ".(?=(\\+|$))|\\+"), 
  new2 = str_replace_all(new1, "(.)\\1+", "\\1")) %>%
  filter(nchar(new2) == nchar(new1)) %>%
  select(ID, Column1 = ColumnA, Value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   ID    Column1  Value
   <chr> <chr>    <int>
 1 A     xa+ya        9
 2 A     xa+yb       10
 3 A     xb+ya        6
 4 A     xb+yb        7
 5 B     ua+va+wa    17
 6 B     ua+va+wb    19
 7 B     ua+vb+wa    14
 8 B     ua+vb+wb    16
 9 B     ub+va+wa    10
10 B     ub+va+wb    12
11 B     ub+vb+wa     7
12 B     ub+vb+wb     9
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(ColumnA = str_c(Column1, Column2)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  group_modify(~ bind_cols(
     split(.x$ColumnA, .x$Column1) %>%
     expand.grid %>% 
     unite(ColumnA, everything(), sep = "+"), 
    Value = split(.x$Value, .x$Column1) %>%
           expand.grid %>% 
           rowSums(.)) ) %>% 
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   ID    ColumnA  Value
   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 A     xa+ya        9
 2 A     xb+ya        6
 3 A     xa+yb       10
 4 A     xb+yb        7
 5 B     ua+va+wa    17
 6 B     ub+va+wa    10
 7 B     ua+vb+wa    14
 8 B     ub+vb+wa     7
 9 B     ua+va+wb    19
10 B     ub+va+wb    12
11 B     ua+vb+wb    16
12 B     ub+vb+wb     9
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), Column1 = c("x", "x", "y", "y", "u", "u", "v", "v", 
"w", "w"), Column2 = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
"a", "b"), Value = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 3L)),
 row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```